# Deleting all files and folders in directory except hidden files using java

Tags: java, swing, svn

I need to delete all the files and folders in a directory but i need to .svn folder in this so that i can commit and delete the folder everytime. My below code worked but it retains .svn parent folder only but rest of its child .svn folders are deleted

my code:

```
      if (pFile.exists() ) {
        System.out.println(pFile.getName());
        if (pFile.isDirectory()) {
            if (pFile.list().length == 0) {
                 System.out.println("0>"+pFile.getName());
                pFile.delete();
            } else {
                System.out.println("1>"+pFile.getName());
                String[] strFiles = pFile.list();

                for (String strFilename : strFiles) {
                    File fileToDelete = new File(pFile, strFilename);
                    System.out.println("2>"+fileToDelete.getName());
                    if(fileToDelete.getName()==".svn")
                    {
                        // Do Nothing
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    delete(fileToDelete);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
             System.out.println("3>"+pFile.getName());
           pFile.delete();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `==".svn"` that is not how String values should be compared. Read more about it in [how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Need to modify condition as below. Here `break` will stop loop where as `continue` will skip only current deletion (ie, folder as .svn)

```
 if(fileToDelete.getName()!=null && fileToDelete.getName().equals(".svn")){
     // Do Nothing
     continue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pFile.isHidden() to check if it is a hidden file.
In addition you can list all files in a folder with File.listFiles() instead of File.list() so you dont have to create a new File.

Answer (score 0):

The other suggestions should solve your issue else you say, you need to delete all files and folders in a directory. So may be you are deleting all child folders that contain .svn in them and so you dont see them remain.